# Deal with the thirst for power of a colleague

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, leadership, teamleader

I am working in a company, and I am having this type of problem: whenever we start a new project a colleague of mine always wants to be the leader of the project.

He is now leading a very important project, and usually this will be enough, but lately he made me understand that in the next period he would like to take the lead in the project I am now leading, which is one of the most important of the company (maybe his behaviour is caused by his ego).

The other people in the company do not care and neither does the director by this change.

I have tried talking to him and explaining why it is not a good behaviour for the company. The other workers do not care about responsibility roles in the company, so having only one person being leader of 2 important projects will only enhance the feeling that there will always be someone who takes the responsibility for the things:

- If he has personal problems then all the projects will suffer;
- With more people leading projects in the company there is more dialogue and we can find better ways of solving problems.

I also have good relationships with my colleagues (except for this one), so **how can I address my other colleagues that the company does not need a man that does all the work (so everyone can do their job properly) and resolve this situation (stopping him for taking over my project) without attacking him personally?**

---

In my previous job, a situation like this happened, and when the leader of all the projects got sick, all the projects were stopped except for the one I was leading, and this lead to a crisis for the company.

The project is composed of two parts: now I am leading the first part. After the first part is completed then we (we inside the company) will decide who will be the leader of the second part. I have also tried to say that it is better if the project is directed as a whole by one person, but I was ignored, so the decision of the director of the second part will happen in the next month.

Comment: You already asked this on another stack exchange. Please don't ask the same question on multiple different stack exchange sites https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/22243/problem-with-the-thirst-of-power-of-a-colleague

Comment: @PhillS He was asked to bring the question here, instead, in the comments in the question you linked to.

Comment: @PhillS It is like nick12000 wrote. Please, if this is not the right stack exchange, tell me where I can post the question.

Comment: Why does he have that power to decide which projects he will lead? Is he somehow "above" you in the "company hierarchy"?